# Check if any variables, named with some prefix, are set?

Tags: batch-file, io-redirection

I want a conditional jump based on whether or not there are any variables, whose names begin with `FOO_`, defined.

I can do this:

```DOS
SET FOO_ && (echo FOO is set) || (echo FOO not set)
```

Which works, but I get additional output that I don't want:

```
Environment variable FOO_  not defined     <--- unwanted
FOO not set
```

How can I suppress this extra output?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to redirect the output to `nul`

```DOS
(SET FOO_ ) >nul 2>&1 && (echo FOO is set) || (echo FOO not set)
```

[Here is some relevant documentation on redirection.](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)